# Numerical solution of Laplace equation on an image

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, harmonic-functions

I want to solve the Laplace equation on a grayscale image, say of size 1024 by 1024. The pixel values are imposed on a closed curve in the middle (say surrounding a quarter of the image area) and free elsewhere. The solution is only required outside the curve and if necessary, we can impose a constant value (such as the average of the outline) on the image edges.

Accuracy of the solution is not required, but speed is. Is there a known way to solve this efficiently, for instance via a multiscale approach ?

Comment: There's the [method of relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(iterative_method)). It's easy to implement, reasonably fast, and it's easy to trade accuracy for speed.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: if I am right, relaxation will propagate the boundary values one pixel farther at every iteration, meaning that it will take hundreds of iterations before reaching the image edges ?

Comment: @YvesDaust Correct. Thus, the speed will be impacted to the size the of the curve in the image, as well as your initial approximation, which is likely a weighted average between the value on the curve and the image boundary.

Comment: I have ImageJ programs that use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to expand an image in a linear combination of some set of images, this work very fast. So, if I had to deal with such a problem I would just generate images corresponding to terms of the multipole expansion, so one image shows gray values given by $\log(r)$, the next shows $\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}$, then comes $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{r}$, next is $\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{r^2}$ etc. etc. Then I make copies of all the images where I mask out everything except the curve and expand the original image.

Comment: This expansion could be used as a first approximation that can be polished up using  the relaxation methods mentioned by Mark McClure.

Comment: @CountIblis: doesn't it mean that I should add the contributions from all pixels of the curve, i.e. sum thousand images ?

Comment: You can generate about 20 or so random images that are solutions of the Laplace equation, e.g. by taking the pixel values to be the real part of arbitrary complex analytic functions. Then you run Gram-Schmidt to obtain an orthogonal set. Then you take your original picture with only the curve and you expand that in the orthogonal bases, but here you must mask all the pixels that are not on the curve. If this linear combination represents the curve well, then applying that to the entire images with the masks removed should be a good first approximation.

Comment: I have a macro for doing Gram-Schmidt and another macro for expanding an image in orthogonal sets created by the Gram Schmidt macro, I would have to tweak that to do the latter with masking. This runs in ImageJ's macro system which is a bit slow. It can be programed in Java and compiled and then it would run a lot faster. But I'm not yet proficient enough in Java programming. For a few dozen images this is not a problem, it takes a few minutes.

Comment: @CountIblis: this is not what I would call fast. I am thinking of a computation under half a second (on CPU).

Comment: @YvesDaoust A proper written Java program would run in a fraction of a second. The problem with my macro as currently written is also that it will ask for input like filenames, number of files, asking you to select the image etc. etc. I wrote this as a general too, for some class of tasks, not to be very fast for some specific task.

Comment: @CountIblis: I begin to understand. Will the decomposition obtained from the orthogonal basis applied to the curve pixels reconstruct the curve (at least approximately) ? The masking will not apply during reconstruction.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, so to get to a first approximation you don't need many pictures, just like you don't need all that many terms from a Fourier series to approximate a function on some interval. So, there is no reason why this step should take a long time if you implement it properly. One other problem with my macro is that while it runs, it displays all the intermediary pictures, but with a proper Java program this can be handled in internal memory, which is much faster. The next step is then to polish up the approximation using relaxation methods.